# Setting up Clusters and work nodes - How do I set KUBECONFIG variable in Windows 10?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I using following link to create :
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_tutorials.html#cs_cluster_tutorial

In Lesson3, Step 3 "Verify that the KUBECONFIG environment variable is set properly.",  I am unable to set the variable KUBECONFIG.

I am able to execute the following command:
ibmcloud ks cluster-config clusternameabc

I am getting following message
The configuration for clusternameabc was downloaded successfully. Export environment variables to start using Kubernetes, with the following message:

> SET KUBECONFIG=C:\Users\AAA.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\customernameabc\kube-config-hou02-clusternameabc.yml

When I run the above SET command in powershell, I just get the prompt back with environment variable not set.

When I  do

> $Env:KUBECONFIG=C:\Users\AAA.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\customernameabc\kube-config-hou02-clusternameabc.yml

Notepad gets opened and this file is shown.  I want to just set the environment variable and unable to. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I tried searching and could not find answers and IBM documentation has only Mac examples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Powershell

1) `$env:KUBECONFIG = "C:\Users\AAA.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\customernameabc\kube-config-hou02-clusternameabc.yml"`

2) `ls env:KUBECONFIG`

Slightly easier to remember.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my tests, you have to wrap the value of the environment environment in double quotes, like so:

```
$Env:KUBECONFIG="C:\Users\AAA.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\customernameabc\kube-config-hou02-clusternameabc.yml"
```

Then, you can check the environment variables in PowerShell via this command:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Env:KUBECONFIG = ibmcloud cs cluster-config --export clusternameabc | Select -First 1 | % {$_.replace("SET KUBECONFIG=","")}
```